# OS X app runs slowly when launched outside of XCode

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I developed a Mac app in Swift that processes a batch of WAV files from a folder (basically, by iterating over the list of files in the specified folder and creating one operation per file in a NSOperationQueue). The app runs really fast when I run it from inside XCode (setting my Run scheme to use the Release version of the app). However, when I open the .app file outside of XCode (either by using the .app file from XCode DerivedData folder or by archiving it), the same app gets ~15x slower. What could be the reason for this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, XCode was linking the project to a version of a custom framework compiled with the Debug flags instead of the Release flags. Cleaning up the project on XCode, manually deleting any copies of the said framework and compiling everything again solved the issue.